# Is there a way to move a file from google form submission into another folder based on a rows criteria in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

is there a way to move a file from google form submission into another folder based on a rows criteria in google sheets?

I would appreciate any assistance. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly your question has two parts: first you want to match a criteria in the responses Sheet. Then, you want to move a file from a folder into another one. If my understanding of the issue is correct, then you can achieve your goal with these easy steps.

In the first place you can use the [`TextFinder`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder) class to look for a match in the response Sheet. If there is a match, then the files should be moved from one Drive folder into another. To run that move you need to open the file first by using [`DriveApp.getFileById()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfilebyidid). Then you can use [`File.moveTo()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#movetodestination) to move it to the other folder by providing the folder identifier (it could be done by using [`DriveApp.getFolderById()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfolderbyidid)). Please, feel free to ask me any additional doubts.

Comment: Thank you. Will give the above suggestion a try.